# how to easymock test this code

Tags: hibernate, easymock

how this code test with easymock

---

```
    return (Long) getHibernateTemplate().execute(
            new HibernateCallback() {
                public Object doInHibernate(Session s) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                    Criteria criteria = s.createCriteria(EntityData.class);
                    criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.like(param, val));
                    return ((Long)criteria.uniqueResult()).longValue();
                }
```

### });

Answer (score 0):

As this is a pure database access operation, I wouldn't mock anything. Just write an unit test, which tests if it returns the correct result and if it's still correct when the data changes.

Therefore you should provide a special datasource for tests, so that your productive system isn't affected. If it's not possible exchange the database configuration, separate your test data by conventions, for example ids starting with 0 are used for tests.

But you could even skip unit testing for this method and write an integration test instead.